# A plot for cross tabulations in R

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to see if each unique `childid` only occur in one unique `schoolid` or not. I have plotted the cross tabulations, but the visual is very busy and unclear.

Is there a better way (by plotting or otherwise) to achieve my goal in R?

(*ps. As an alternative, I was also told to fit a mixed-model and plot the random-effects but as shown below the image is super small and unclear.*)

```
dd <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/3.csv')
cross_tab <- xtabs(~ schoolid + childid, dd)

plot(cross_tab)

library(lme4)

m31 <- lmer(math~year+(1|schoolid/childid), data = dd)

image(getME(m31,"Zt"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are 315 unique IDs across 10 schools in your data set. Obviously it will look busy and unclear, no matter how you cut it. 

Maybe the better question is, what are you trying to show? Giving an example of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way (no plot).

With Base R. You can calculate a contingency table and then count how many times for each `childid` you have a positive values for a `schoolid+chilid` match. If it's more than 1 than you have the insight you were looking for.

```
x <- colSums(table(dd$schoolid, dd$childid) > 0) 
x[x>1]
#> named numeric(0)
```

With `dplyr`. You `distinct` each `schoolid+childid` match and then you count if `childid` appears more than once.

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% distinct(schoolid, childid) %>% count(childid) %>% filter(n>1)
#> [1] childid n      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I like your base R answer. I wanted to do something like that but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Checks sizes of unique schoolid's per studentid.

```
dd %>% group_by(childid) %>% summarize(ns_per_id = length(unique(schoolid))) %>% 
summarise(unique(ns_per_id))
```

> ```
> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
> # A tibble: 1 x 1
>   `unique(ns_per_id)`
>          <int>
> 1            1
> ```